# How to get JSON in data table fnDrawCallback function?

Tags: jquery, datatables

How we get JSON in `fnDrawCallback` function? Actually I send extra parameter in JSON and i want to get it in `fnDrawCallback` function.

Comment: How do you initialise the dataTable - please show some code.

Answer (score 2):

you can access the data throught the object api.

Example, this json return:

```
$output = array(
"iTotalRecords" => $qty,
"iTotalinvoicesum" => $totalinvoicesum,
"iTotalbalancesum" => $totalbalancesum,
"iTotalDisplayRecords" => $qty,
"aaData" => array()
);
```

On the callback you can do this:

```
"drawCallback": function( settings ) {
                var api = this.api();
                var json = api.ajax.json();
                $( api.column( 5 ).footer() ).html(
                    '<b>$ '+json.iTotalinvoicesum+'</b>'
                );
                $( api.column( 6 ).footer() ).html(
                    '<b>$ '+json.iTotalbalancesum+'</b>'
                );
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi below code might helpful for you I also needed extra parameters to set in header apart form datatable list :

```
"ajax":{
            url :file url,
            method: "get",
            error: function() {
                $("#succmsg").html("error");
            },
            dataSrc: function(headerdata){
             $('#someid').html(headerdata.variablename);
             return headerdata.data;    
         }
        },
```